# How can I capture from my Windows Hello/IR camera using OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OpenCV to capture frames from both my front and back cameras, but I cannot access the third IR camera. In device manager it is separate under biometric devices as "Windows Hello Face Software Device", but I do not know how to capture from it, or even if it is possible at all. This is the code I have to capture an image from the two normal cameras:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap = VideoCapture(0);
    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame;
    imshow("Display Window", frame);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: This camera doesnt have its own driver ? I think you should use its SDK